# $\frac 1 {\overline {f(1/\ \overline z)}}$ is differentiable for $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $S=\{z \in \mathbb C : |z|<1\}$. Suppose that $f: S \to \mathbb C$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain. Suppose further than $f(z)$ is never zero.

> I want to show that $g(z):=\frac 1 {\overline {f(1/\ \overline z)}}$ is differentiable for $|z|>1$.

My first thought was to apply the composition-of-differentiable-functions-is-differentiable theorem. But, alas, the complex conjugation function is not differentiable.

I also thought of applying a theorem which states that, if $f$ is analytic in some open connected set $D$ which contains a segment of the x-axis and is symmertic about that axis, then $[\forall z \in D,\overline {f(z)}=f(\overline z)] \iff [f(x)$ is real for each $x$ in the segment$]$.

The above theorem would be helpful if $f(x)$ was real for each $x\in (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$, but this isn't necessarily true. For example, it isn't true if $f(z) \equiv iz$.

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate from the fact that if $g$ is holomorphic in a domain $D$ the  so is $\overline {f(\overline {z})}$ on it domain $\{\overline {z}:z \in D\}$. [one way to see this is to use power series. Another way is to verify C-R equations].

Comment: Or you could just go directly to the definition: if $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar{z})}$ then $\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}$ is the complex conjugate of $\frac{f(\bar z + \bar h) - f(\bar z)}{\bar h}$; but as $h \to 0$, also $\bar h \to 0$, so this quotient goes to $f'(\bar z)$ implying that $g$ is differentiable and $g'(z) = \overline{f'(\bar z)}$.

Comment: Though actually, if $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ then $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is holomorphic in $\bar D$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the comment.